# How to remove Text Selection Text coming in contextual actionbar in android

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar

I have set textView.setTextIsSelectable on textviews in my android app. It is working fine. But when I Long Click on any Textview it shows contextual actionbar in which it shows Back button, "Text Selection" text, select all and copy option.

Now, I want to remove this text from this contextual bar, how can I do this. I just want to show options, do now want to show text on action bar.

Please help me if anybody have any idea here, thank you so much in advanced.

Comment: are you using menu file for inflating context menu? post it here.

Comment: I am not using anything, it is giving me the default contextual bar. Please help me if you have any idea here, how can I remove that text from contextual bar.

Comment: Can I get any update on this please.